# Status/Notification bar can't be accessed while inside full screen apps (GS4 - i9505 CM 12.1 Lollipop 5.1.1)

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 5.1-lollipop, notification-bar

When I'm running a game or playing a video on full-screen it's simply impossible to push down the status bar. So I have to close the APP whenever I want to see the time, battery percentage or answer a notification. AM I the only one having this problem? Does someone know anything on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once nobody was able to help me, I decided to share the answer I got by myself. I was bored and had nothing to do so I started going here and there trhough the conf. menu and I found out an option to solve it. It's under Developer options. There's an option enabled called Block touch gesture events  or something like this. You should just disable it then you're able to pull down the status bar over the full screen apps. Hope it helps someone. Thanks anyway.